# Best and fastest way to loot other ships

Tags: eve-online

Question is simple, I do not want to try and find where the small ship wrecks and try to loot it. I am sure there is a faster way without searching and looting manually.

Comment: You should expand your question a bit. Are you tlaking about reaching/finding the wrecks within some specific location (like a mission site) or are you talking about finding such mission sites with wrecks from other peoples?

Comment: finding wrecks in a location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to finding the wrecks, the easiest way to find them is through the overview (configured to display wrecks).

As to a better way to loot than manual looting, an answer to all your plights,
 
[Mobile](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Personal_Deployable_Structures#Mobile_Tractor_Unit) 
[Tractor](http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Mobile_Structure#Mobile_Tractor_Unit) 
[Unit](http://eve.battleclinic.com/item_database.php?id=i33475)
MTU for short, this little baby will tractor in and loot every wreck in range all by itself. All you have to do is carry it in your cargo hold to the spot (too bad it takes up a lot of space), deploy it and protect it while you wreak mayhem on every wreckable thing in the vicinity.

But if you lack the space for an MTU, you can always use a normal tractor unit and loot the not-so-distant-anymore ships yourself, all at the cost of a high slot.

Comment: how to configure to display wrecks?

Comment: @Esq for a guide, see https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Overview_scanner